# Padding and margin on pack layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

#### Introduction

I've been searching over *StackOverflow* about padding/margin application with the circle packing layout, but no useful question neither answer have been found.

#### What I have

I have a pack layout with circles inside circles that looks like below:

[image]

The entered circles are rendered by:

```
var selection = child.datum(data).selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack.nodes, function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

var newG = enter
    .append("g")
    .classed("node", true)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return translate(d.x, d.y);
    });

  newG
    .append("circle") // Outer circle
    .attr("r", function(d) { return 0; })
    .style("fill", "green")
    .append("circle") // Inner circle
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.r - (d.r / 10); // Border is 10% of the circle radius
    });
```

#### Expectations

Increasing the radius of the first circle won't work. I really didn't try so many things because I have no idea what I should try for that. All the `circle` elements are based by a `g`, but increasing the translation of that `g` element would cause a misunderstaning in the position of the other elements. Everything I increase there only increase the scale of the circle and its sub-elements, but what is necessary is a padding among them. I have a basic [working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/haskellcamargo/p9pnjrxp/).

#### Question

**Is there a simple way to apply padding/margin on a pack layout or a built-in feature?**.

#### Edited

Using the built-in `pack.padding()` will move away the circles from each other. This solves the problem in part, but the parent yet is reached by the circles. It is an inner space:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`pack.padding()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#padding).

Comment: The problem is that `pack.padding` doesn't really moves away the inner circles from their parent. http://imgur.com/Cn6bgtq

Comment: Yeah, setting a margin isn't supported by the pack layout.

Comment: I've added a `margin` parameter to the pack layout that does what I think you want and submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/2536) to D3, so this may be available soon.

Comment: Well, that really solves the problem. I thank you very much for that! If you wish, please, post this as an answer to help future users in order to help them to find it and that I may close the question as *solved*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some of the way there with [`pack.padding()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#padding). This won't change the distance of children to their parents -- this is current not supported in D3.

I've implemented a `margin` parameter that does it and submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/2536), so hopefully it will be available soon.